# using score() in SQL for multiple parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, rank, keyword-search

I have 3 parameters i have to score using the following formula:

```
rank = 6*score(name)=3*score(diagnosis)+score(description);
```

I need 3 scores for that right?

I know that for 1 score, you would write a query like this:

```
    SELECT score(1), itemName 
FROM item WHERE contains(description, 'database', 1) > 0 
order by score(1) desc;
```

how would I do this for finding a keyword in a database table if I have 3 fields to search( name, description, diagnosis?)

I had this:

```
SELECT score(1), patient_name, score(2), diagnosis, score(3),description 
FROM radiology_record r 
WHERE (not sure what to put in the WHERE SECTION)
ORDER BY (6*score(1)+3*score(2)+score(3)) desc;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: oracle. i forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution based on two tables i needed.  Radiology record and persons.

```
    SELECT 6*(score(1)+score(2))+3*score(3)+score(4) as rank
    FROM radiology_record r, persons p 
    WHERE p.person_id = r.patient_id AND contains(first_name, 'dead',   1)>0 
    OR contains(last_name, 'dead', 2)>0 OR contains(diagnosis,'dead', 3) > 0 
    OR contains(description, 'dead', 4) > 0 

    ORDER BY (6*(score(1)+score(2))+3*score(3)+score(4));
```